# google_link,google_text = google(result) make cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object djanog BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-templates

i try to make search google with BeautifulSoup in socialnetwork django site project i download it as open source and when i try to make that i receve a error message cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

thats search.py

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

## done

def google(s):
links = []
text = []

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36'
headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
r=None
if r is not None :
    r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + s, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for g in soup.find_all('div', class_='yuRUbf'):
        a = g.find('a')
        t = g.find('h3')
        links.append(a.get('href'))
        text.append(t.text)   

        return links, text
```

and thats the view.py

def results(request):
if request.method == "POST":

```
    result = request.POST.get('search')
    
    google_link,google_text = google(result)
    google_data = zip(google_link,google_text)
   

    if result == '':
        return redirect('Home')
    else:
        return render(request,'results.html',{'google': google_data })
```

and thats a template

```
 {% for i,j in google  %}
         <a href="{{ i }}" class="btn mt-3 w-100 lg-12 md-12">{{ j }}</a><br>
        
 {% endfor %}
```

i reseve the message cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object for google_link,google_text = google(result)

Answer (score 0):

not None returns True if the objects are not identical. In your case, **r=None** and **'if r is not None'** is immediately checked, so False is returned. All lines below the if statement are not involved. Probably because of this: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object. Because he doesn't exist.

The rest of the code is working. I modified it a bit and if yours doesn't work, use mine. The search word is entered in the form field, in case of successful saving of the form, the result is transferred to the 'results' view. If empty, then the page will show: **'result = empty'**.

views.py

```
def google(s):
    USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36'
    headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
    r = None
    links = []
    text = []

    r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + s, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for g in soup.find_all('div', class_='yuRUbf'):
        a = g.find('a')
        t = g.find('h3')
        links.append(a.get('href'))
        text.append(t.text)

    return links, text

def form(request):

    return render(request, 'form.html')

def results(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.POST.get('search')
        google_link, google_text = google(result)
        google_data = zip(google_link, google_text)

        if result == '':
            return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>result = empty</h1>')
        else:
            return render(request, 'results.html', {'google': google_data})
```

form.hml

```
<form method='post' action="{% url 'results' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Name:<br> <input name='search'/></p>
    <input type='submit' value='Send'/>
</form>
```

results.html

```
{% for i,j in google  %}
<a href="{{ i }}" class="btn mt-3 w-100 lg-12 md-12">{{ j }}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('form/', form, name='form'),
    path('results/', results, name='results'),
]
```

Here's how it works for me:
[image]

Comment: thank you for your replay i delete "if r is not none" and the same result i got

Comment: @ashrafsadik updated the answer, added a gif.  I filled out the word in the form for the search and clicked the submit button. After 1-2 seconds, a page with links appeared. Show the address at which you went to the page with the form.

Comment: It is also possible that the url name "{% url 'results' %}" is specified in the form. Then if you didn’t write these paths in urlpatterns, then that’s why it doesn’t work.

Comment: i make url in urls of the all project  path('results/',views.results,name='results'),

Comment: I have done it this way: the form path('form/', form, name='form') is called in it, the value for the search is entered and the button for submitting the form is pressed. The form sends a value to path('results/', results, name='results') which displays the search result.  This row: request.POST.get('search') gets the search word from the form.

Comment: do you have anydisk to saw my code and know what a mistake i have done if you have give me a number

Comment: If you call immediately: http://localhost:8000/results/,
then you get what you got, namely: The view bboard.views.results didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
And if you print print(request.method) it will default to GET and print(request.POST.get('search')) it will be None since you didn't pass anything to the view.

Comment: To put it even simpler, how do you want +s(word to search) to go into the view if you pass None. To do this, you need to get it, for example, from a form, as I did. To check, replace s, for example with 'usd' and you will see that it is. Only in your code you have to remove the lines with POST and result.

Comment: @ashrafsadik happened?

Comment: just use my code and go to: http://localhost:8000/form/

Comment: in urls when i wrote path('form/', form, name='form'), there is a mistake with yloow line  that form is not defined form in the middle

Comment: did you create a form.html template?

Comment: and when i searsh usd there is no mistake massage but there is no result also

Comment: i make it and i search on it but after i add views.form insted of form in the middle in urls file

Comment: i.e. the field with 'Name' you see?

Comment: but the page of result is empty

Comment: when you go to: http://localhost:8000/form/ what do you see? Take a screenshot and show in your question.

Comment: its look like your photo in the video above

Comment: to use path('form/', form, name='form') you need to use: from .views import *  But, it doesn't matter, it's possible according to yours: path('form/', views.form, name='form') with connection: from . import views.

Comment: you now have this: path('results/', views.results, name='results'), ?

Comment: yes i wrote path('results/',views.results,name='results'),

Comment: the page is shown with button google but there isn't  any result

Comment: Try entering another word. And in the def results(request): view, before the line: if request.method == 'POST': put print('method', request.method). Write what is printed.

Comment: i print it but where i can see the result i used visual studio code is that print in terminal

Comment: i try another search word but its the same

Comment: OK, very well. I can't help anymore.

Comment: thank you for your time i appreciate your patient